# Maclaurin series of $f(x)=\sinh(1/x)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

As we know the formula of Maclaurin series for $f(x) = \sinh(x)$ is $f(x)=x+x^3/3! + x^5/5!+\ldots$

Could anyone tell me what is the Maclaurin series of $f(x)=\sinh(1/x)$?

Comment: $0$ is an essential singularity so it shouldn't have a Laurent expansion (in $x$).

Comment: While you'll get $f(x)=\frac 1x+\frac 1{3!x^3} +\ldots$ at infinity.

Comment: @anon, it does have a Laurent expansion (see RaymondManzoni's comment).

Comment: @vonbrand: You're right, I noted in a comment on the deleted answer that I was confusing Laurent series with formal Laurent series in my comment above. For OP's purposes, replace "Laurent" with "Maclaurin" in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Macluarin series for $\sinh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$. If you use the standard formula for Macluarin series which is:

$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3...$$

And you try to evaluate $f(0)$, you will get undefined as $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined. Thus, you cannot construct a Maclaurin series for $\sinh \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.